# Values from JSP are not getting to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a very weird problem.

I have a jsp in which I populated values from database through jstl tags.  I want to read the checked rows into Javascript, but I am not able to get these values into my js file.

I used jQuery, dojo and normal JavaScript to read these values and display in web console, they just don't work.

Can some one please review and let me know why the values cannot be read in javascript? Below is the code snippet of my jsp.

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="emailItemType"
               items="${emailFormModel.getEMailFormDisplayData().getEMailItemTypes()}">
      <tr class="accordion-toggle collapsed" id="accordion1"
          data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
        <th class="expand-button"></th>
        <th>
          <c:out value="${emailItemType.key}"/>
        </th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="dijit.form.CheckBox" id="select_all">
        </th>

      </tr>
      <tr class="hide-table-padding">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
            <c:forEach var="emailItemTypeAttr" items="${emailItemType.value}"
                       varStatus="idx">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" data-dojo-attach-point="checkBox"
                         name="checkBox" id="checkbox"
                         data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox"
                         class="dijitCheckBox" value="check1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-nowrap" id="sourceValue"
                     name="sourceValue" data-dojo-attach-point="sourceValue"
                     value="${emailItemTypeAttr.getSourceValue()}">
                  <c:out value="${emailItemTypeAttr.getSourceValue()}"/>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-nowrap"
                     data-dojo-attach-point="userIdValue" name="userIdValue">
                  <c:out value="${emailItemTypeAttr.getUserIdValue()}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-nowrap"
                     data-dojo-attach-point="objectId" name="objectId">
                  <c:out value="${emailItemTypeAttr.getObjectId()}"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Below is my Js code :

```js
dojo code :
    require([
        "dojo/request",   
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/dom-attr",
        "dijit/registry",
         "dojo/text!./templates/email.jsp"
    ], function (request,dom,domattr,registry,template) {
        var source = thisForm.sourceValue.get('value');
        console.log("var is :" + source);       

        var checkboxes = registry.findWidgets(dom.byId('checkbox'));
        console.log(checkboxes);    

       var SourceValue = registry.byId("sourceValue").get('value');
        console.log("sourceValue from regitry id:"+ SourceValue);
         var sourceValue = dojo.byId("sourceValue").value;
         console.log("sourceValue from dojobyid:"+ sourceValue);

       });
```

JavaScript code throws error saying it is undefined:

```js
var sourceValue = document.getElementById("sourceValue").textContent;;
console.log("sourceValue:"+sourceValue);
```

Code below is in jquery, which is for selecting all the checkboxes when the above check box is checked. This works but doesn't still display the source value.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var sourceValue = $('#sourceValue').val();
  console.log('sourceValue:' + sourceValue);
  $('#select_all').on('click', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('.dijitCheckBox').each(function () {
        this.checked = true;
      });
    } else {
      $('.dijitCheckBox').each(function () {
        this.checked = false;
      });
    }
  });

  $('.dijitCheckBox').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.dijitCheckBox:checked').length == $('.dijitCheckBox').length) {
      $('#select_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#select_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Nothing just works, please help as I am working on this for a long time.

Comment: You are repeating ids.  Namely the `sourceValue` id.  Ids are expected to be unique.

Comment: Also `<div>` tags do not have a `value` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Taplar for your response , can you please let me know how do I  read repeated id .

Comment: You don't.  That's the point of my comment.  If you need to repeat an identifier, you need to use a class instead.

Comment: I dint get , can you elaborate on how to use a class .

Comment: `class="whateverNameYouNeed"`

Comment: well , I tried that too but I was getting an error when I was trying to read through that class

Comment: you need to get `sourceValue` on click of something ?

Comment: Yes , when I check the input type , the value should be fetched , but I also want to read the values populated to javascript .

Comment: did you tried my code?

Comment: hi yes , that helped , I had to change according my requirement , still you gave an insight how it could be done as I am not aware of jquery. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If that was helpful ,don't forget  to set answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checkbox `dijitCheckBox` is clicked you can use `find()` and `closest()` method of jquery to get the value which you need using `classname`.

**Demo Code**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#select_all').on('click', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('.dijitCheckBox').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;
        //checkbox->closest <tr>--> find class with name sourceValue
        console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('.sourceValue').text() + " | ");
      });
      //same do with other div just change classs name 
    } else {
      $('.dijitCheckBox').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
      });
    }
  });

  $('.dijitCheckBox').on('click', function() {
    //when checkbox is clicked find closest tr with class sourceValue
    var source_value = $(this).closest('tr').find('.sourceValue').text();
    console.log("sourceValue:"+source_value);
    if ($('.dijitCheckBox:checked').length == $('.dijitCheckBox').length) {
      $('#select_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#select_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="accordion-toggle collapsed" id="accordion1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
        <th class="expand-button"></th>
        <th>
          <!--<c:out value="${emailItemType.key}" />-->123
        </th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="dijit.form.CheckBox" id="select_all">
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-toggle collapsed" id="accordion1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">
        <th class="expand-button"></th>
        <th>
          <!--<c:out value="${emailItemType.key}" />-->345
        </th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="dijit.form.CheckBox" id="select_all">
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hide-table-padding">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="checkbox" data-dojo-attach-point="checkBox" name="checkBox" id="checkbox" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" class="dijitCheckBox" value="check1">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 text-nowrap sourceValue" id="sourceValue" name="sourceValue" data-dojo-attach-point="sourceValue" value="${emailItemTypeAttr.getSourceValue()}">Abc </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 text-nowrap" data-dojo-attach-point="userIdValue" name="userIdValue"> 1</div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 text-nowrap" data-dojo-attach-point="objectId" name="objectId"> 2 </div>
            </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hide-table-padding">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="checkbox" data-dojo-attach-point="checkBox" name="checkBox" id="checkbox" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" class="dijitCheckBox" value="check1">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 text-nowrap sourceValue" id="sourceValue" name="sourceValue" data-dojo-attach-point="sourceValue" value="${emailItemTypeAttr.getSourceValue()}"> xyz </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 text-nowrap" data-dojo-attach-point="userIdValue" name="userIdValue"> 2 </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 text-nowrap" data-dojo-attach-point="objectId" name="objectId">3</div>
            </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```